# Unable to setup WiFi on Arch Linux and Realtek rtl8192cu

Tags: wireless, archlinux, wifi, realtek

I'm trying to follow [Wireless Setup - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wireless_Setup) to set up my WiFi, yet running into some issues:

```
[root@alarmpi ~]# dmesg | grep -i rtl8192cu
[    7.697779] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8192cu
[root@alarmpi ~]# lsmod | grep 8192cu
8192cu                487313  0 
[root@alarmpi ~]# iw dev wlan0 scan
nl80211 not found.
[root@alarmpi ~]#
```

Please advise.

Comment: Note that the RTL8192CU kernel driver is loaded automatically in the latest Raspian distribution.

Comment: @syb0rg you should've left your instruction) I wanted to try them out if I wouldn't find any other solution. I'm on Arch Linux not Raspian though(

Comment: [It looks like you are not alone in your issue](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=16849).  I removed my answer because I did not think that it would solve the issue (based on past experiences of my own).  [Here is the link](https://github.com/ksclarke/rtl8192cu) if you still want to try it out (instructions are in the `readme`).

Comment: How about the listing for the actual device in `lsusb -v`?  You should say what it is.

Comment: @goldilocks output from `lsusb -v` is at http://pastebin.com/U8aY0NMc

Comment: Hmph. `ID 0bda:8176 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188CUS 802.11n WLAN Adapter` -- that's exactly what I use with the pi, `8192cu` driver, raspbian.  It does not run quite as well on the pi as on a normal linux box -- has to reconnect occasionally. But it works :( Maybe it's a power issue (I believe that's why mine runs worse on the pi).  What else do you have plugged into the USB?

Comment: @goldilocks Realtek (wifi) & Logitech (wireless keyboard/mouse)

Comment: I have the same issue in my `raspbian`. I deleted the entry from `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` and reboot. Also, the problem seems to be related to the driver. I downloaded from Realtek's website and compiled.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to get the Realtek RTL8188CUS (EdiMax EW-7811Un) device to work properly under Arch Linux by using a later kernel. It seems according to [this discussion](http://archlinuxarm.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=6834&start=10) that it's been working since kernel-3.13, but the default kernel that is currently installed by Arch Linux is version 3.12.26 (as of 5sept14). So to install a newer kernel you need to install the `linux-raspberrypi-latest` package (currently 3.16.1):

```
pacman -S linux-raspberrypi-latest
```

Then reboot and you should have a system that talks to the Wifi using [nl80211](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/developers/Documentation/nl80211) and hence commands such as [iw](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Documentation/iw) and [hostapd](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Documentation/hostapd) will now work properly.

EDIT[14feb15]: Unfortunately the 'linux-raspberrypi-latest' package appears to have been discontinued. The latest Arch kernel now uses the Realtek driver (v4.0.2_9000.20130911), as opposed to the upstream-linux (rtlwifi) driver, which is more stable for normal use but **does not** provide for monitor mode. If you want to use the monitor mode driver you'll have to build the (rtlwifi) kernel module. Buliding the module isn't too hard - it's simplest to cross-compile the whole kernel on another Linux box. To enable the rtlwifi drivers you'll need to uncomment them from the [raspberrypi kernel wireless config](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/tree/master/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi) (Kconfig and Makefile) then enable rtlwifi when you run make menuconfig.

Answer (score 0):

Using wext driver & iwconfig works for me, see: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/WPA_supplicant#Specifying_driver

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. If you could include the important info from the link it would make your answer more useful and help keep this site/Q:A more useful in the future, as including this info protects against link rot.